# I'm working on a project, keep getting swift error "Argument passed to call that takes no argument"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Working on a SnapChat-esque project in terms of the sliding pages. I keep getting Argument passed to call that takes no argument on these three lines of code. I've looked everywhere, but it's dependent on the lines of code.

```
var view1 = View1(coder: NSCoder(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
var view2 = View2(coder: NSCoder(x: xOrigin, y: CGFloat(0), width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
var view3 = View3(coder: NSCoder(x: xOrigin * 2, y: CGFloat(0), width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
```

Comment: What are all of those arguments you are passing to `NSCoder`? That's not even remotely close to correct. [Edit] your question with what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: Not quite sure, but it looks like you're using the wrong initializer. Use `View1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0…)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error complains because `NSCoder()` takes no arguments.

Nevertheless this particular initializer `init(coder` `of UIView` is called by the framework when creating the object from a nib file.

As already mentioned in the comments you probably want to use `init(frame`

```
let view1 = View1(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: self.view.frame.size))
let view2 = View2(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xOrigin, y:0.0), size: self.view.frame.size))
let view3 = View3(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xOrigin * 2, y:0.0), size: self.view.frame.size))
```

Comment: so originally, I had it like so
' let view1 = View1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        let view2 = View2(frame: CGRect(x: xOrigin, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        let view3 = View3(frame: CGRect(x: xOrigin * 2, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)) '

but then Xcode said to type NSCoder. @vadian